# Fast check if element is in MATLAB matrix

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization

I would like to verify whether an element is present in a MATLAB matrix.

At the beginning, I implemented as follows:

```
if ~isempty(find(matrix(:) == element))
```

which is obviously slow. Thus, I changed to:

```
if sum(matrix(:) == element) ~= 0
```

but this is again slow: I am calling a lot of times the function that contains this instruction, and I lose 14 seconds each time!

Is there a way of further optimize this instruction?

Thanks.

Comment: you could try [`ismember`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) but I am not sure it will be faster. If your `matrix` is 2D, you could also try `sum(sum(matrix==element))`, this would avoid unfolding the matrix by using `(:)` and may be save a bit of time.

Comment: 14 seconds! How big is your matrix? Is it a matrix of doubles (what is `class(matrix)` and `class(element)`?)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need to know if a value exists in a matrix, using the second argument of find to specify that you just want one value will be slightly faster (25-50%) and even a bit faster than using `sum`, at least on my machine. An example:

```
matrix = randi(100,1e4,1e4);
element = 50;
~isempty(find(matrix(:)==element,1))
```

However, in recent versions of Matlab (I'm using R2014b), [`nnz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) is finally faster for this operation, so:

```
matrix = randi(100,1e4,1e4);
element = 50;
nnz(matrix==element)~=0
```

On my machine this is about 2.8 times faster than any other approach (including using `any`, strangely) for the example provided. To my mind, this solution also has the benefit of being the most readable.

Comment: On my laptop, `any` is faster than testing for `nnz`

Comment: @Adrien: You're probably using an older `version` of Matlab. `nnz` has long been slower than seemingly more complex schemes, but it looks like it has finally been optimized. On my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.10.1 and R2014), the example above takes 0.18 seconds using `nnz`, vs. 0.51 seconds for `any` and `find`. I would have though that using `any` would be faster myself.

Comment: I am using R2014a on a MacBook Pro (OSX 10.9.5). For a 30000 by 30000 matrix. the `nnz` way takes 1.8 seconds independently of the position of the match ( `nnz(matrix==matrix(1))` or `nnz(matrix==matrix(end))` ). The  `any` takes between 1.2 and 1.6 seconds depending on the position of the match. I assume that if `any` is coded right it exits as soon as it finds a match while `nnz` needs to examine the whole matrix.  This said I think we are arguing on a quite minor issue :)

Comment: So it looks like the speed-up may begin with R2014b and later then (I suppose it might have something to do with the OS, but I doubt it).

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, there are several things you could try to improve performance:

1. following your initial idea, i would go for the function `any` to test is any of the equality tests had a success:

   `if any(matrix(:) == element)`

I tested this on a 1000 by 1000 matrix and it is faster than the solutions you have tested.

2. I do not think that the unfolding `matrix(:)` is penalizing since it is equivalent to a reshape and Matlab does this in a smart way where it does not actually allocate and move memory since you are not modifying the temporary object `matrix(:)`
3. If your does not change between the calls to the function or changes rarely you could simply use another vector containing all the elements of your matrix, but sorted. This way you could use a more efficient search algorithm O(log(N)) test for the presence of your element.
4. I personally like the `ismember` function for this kind of problems. It might not be the fastest but for non critical parts of the code it greatly improves readability and code maintenance (and I prefer to spend one hour coding something that will take day to run than spending one day to code something that will run in one hour (this of course depends on how often you use this program, but it is something one should never forget)
5. If you can have a sorted copy of the elements of your matrix, you could consider using the undocumented Matlab function [ismembc](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/ismembc-undocumented-helper-function) but remember that inputs must be sorted non-sparse non-NaN values.
6. If performance really is critical you might want to write your own mex file and for this task you could even include some simple parallelization using openmp.

Hope this helps,

Adrien.